# how to insert the data using codeiginter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeiginter,how to insert the data into table using codeiginter

my controller code;

```
$data = array(
        'subgrpname' => $this->input->post('subgrpname'),
        'grpname'=> $this->input->post('grpname'),
        'pltype'=> $this->input->post('pltype')
    );
```

Comment: what is your table name ?

Comment: This link will help you.
https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple form use internet to search it

```
$data = array(
            'subgrpname' => $this->input->post('subgrpname'),
            'grpname'=> $this->input->post('grpname'),
            'pltype'=> $this->input->post('pltype')
        );  
        $this->db->insert('tablename',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share `reusable code approach` by following the MVC coding style

My Controller

```
$table = 'table_name';
$data = array(
  'subgrpname' => $this->input->post('subgrpname'),
  'grpname'=> $this->input->post('grpname'),
  'pltype'=> $this->input->post('pltype')
);
$record_id = $this->Common_Model->insert_into_table($table, $data);
```

My Common_Model

```
function insert_into_table($table, $data) {
    // echo "<pre>";print_r($data);exit;
    $insert = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    if ($insert) {
        return $insert_id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can use this model function as much time as you want.